# compiler errors with function declaration c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, syntax-error, unresolved-external

I get the following compiler error when I try to build my program:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall OddsCalculator::is_straight_flush(__int64)" (?is_straight_flush@OddsCalculator@@QAE_N_J@Z) referenced in function _main
```

I figured this was an issue of scope since I did not put "OddsCalculator::" in front of the function. However, when I go to fix that, I get this error:

```
odds_calculator.cpp(568): error C2589: 'bool': illegal token on right side of '::'
```

I haven't been able to find anything online that matches this error, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

This is main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "odds_calculator.h"

int main() {
    OddsCalculator calc;

    // hand: KH QH  table: AH JH TH 2D 6S
    std::cout << calc.is_straight_flush(0x7c201000) << std::endl;
}
```

This is what the function looks like in odds_calculator.h:

```
#ifndef ODDS_CALCULATOR_H
#define ODDS_CALCULATOR_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

class OddsCalculator {
    public:
        // other functions
        bool is_straight_flush(long long in_play);
};

#endif
```

This is what the function looks like in odds_calculator.cpp:

```
#include "odds_calculator.h"

OddsCalculator::bool is_straight_flush(long long in_play) {
    // code
}
```

I'm using VS2015 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt, and I use the command `cl /EHsc main.cpp odds_calculator.cpp` to compile. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us your entire code, or even better, a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, accidentally posted this before I finished editing :p

Comment: _"I get the following compiler error"_ Except that is not a compiler error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
bool OddsCalculator::is_straight_flush(long long in_play) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: I want to facepalm lol. Thank you.

Comment: You should **explain** your answers, rather than just dumping code on people.